# How can I compile the TypeScript project while ignoring all the errors?

Tags: typescript

I'm building a prototype project, and it has a bunch of TypeScript errors. I want to try quickly compiling it while ignoring all the errors, and get around to fixing them at a later time.

I know about adding `// @ts-ignore` comment at the beginning of the file, but how can I do that for ALL the files? Is there some kind of flag I can add to `tsc`, or some linke I can add to `tsconfig.json` to make it ignore all the errors entirely and compile anyway?

Answer (score 6):

To be clear:

#### This does not Compile

tsconfig.json:

```
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
```

This will not compile. It will create the outDir (/dist folder), but only containing the log with errors of the compile.

#### This does Compile

tsconfig.json:

```
    "noEmit": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have [`noEmit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit) and/or [`noEmitOnError`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError) option set to true in `tsconfig` or as command line argument tsc *will* compile `.js` files regardless of typescript errors.